# Append objects to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need the values for the below TDs in a JavaScript array that I can loop through in another part of my code later on:

```
    <table>
        <tr><td class="drdsclient">DSCDS201020101</td></tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
            <td class="maxonlval notopborder">30</td>
            <td class="maxonlnotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
            <td class="defretruleval notopborder">No default Retention rule set</td>
            <td class="defretrulenotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
            <td class="defschedval notopborder">No default Schedule set</td>
            <td class="defschednotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="drcheck"> <td class="drdsclient">DSCDS901999102</td></tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Maximum online generations:</td>
            <td class="maxonlval notopborder">29</td>
            <td class="maxonlnotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Retention Rule set:</td>
            <td class="defretruleval notopborder">30 days</td>
            <td class="defretnotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="drcheck">
            <td>Default Backup Schedule set:</td>
            <td class="defschedval notopborder">Monday to Friday @ 21:00</td>
            <td class="defschednotes notopborder">notes</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Tried the below JS code:

```
var array = $('.drdsclient').map(function() {
  var $client = $(this);
  var $rows = $client.closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(.drdsclient)');

  var obj = { 
    drdsc: $client.text()
  };

  $rows.each(function() { 
    obj['maxonlval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.maxonlval').text();
    obj['defretruleval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.defretruleval').text();
    obj['defschedval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.defschedval').text();
  });

  return obj;
}).get();
```

But objects are duplicated:

```
[0]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS201020101"
    [maxonlval] => "3029"
    [defretruleval] => "No default Retention rule set30 days"
    [defschedval] => "No default Schedule setMonday to Friday @ 21:00"
[1]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS901999102"
    [maxonlval] => "3029"
    [defretruleval] => "No default Retention rule set30 days"
    [defschedval] => "No default Schedule setMonday to Friday @ 21:00"
```

Ideally if I can have something like below:

```
[0]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS201020101"
    [maxonlval] => "30"
    [defretruleval] => "No default Retention rule set"
    [defschedval] => "No default Schedule set"
[1]
    [drdsc] => "DSCDS901999102"
    [maxonlval] => "29"
    [defretruleval] => "30 days"
    [defschedval] => "Monday to Friday @ 21:00"
```

Comment: Try replacing `$rows.each(function()` with `$rows.each(function(key, value)` then also replace `$('.drcheck').find` with `$(value).find` try if that works

Comment: Blank values: [maxonlval] => ""

Comment: And what if you do `$(key).find`? Just curious ;)

Comment: Nope, still blank values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe replace this part

```
  $rows.each(function() { 
    obj['maxonlval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.maxonlval').text();
    obj['defretruleval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.defretruleval').text();
    obj['defschedval'] = $('.drcheck').find('td.defschedval').text();
  });
```

with

```
obj['maxonlval'] = $rows.find('td.maxonlval').text();
obj['defretruleval'] = $rows.find('td.defretruleval').text();
obj['defschedval'] = $rows.find('td.defschedval').text();
```

Note no loop over `$rows`

Comment: Well that was simple. Thank you